# Tomcat deploy my project twice

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, tomcat7, quartz-scheduler

Tomcat deploy my project twice. is anybody faced and solved this issue?. This is spring project and I am using quartz scheduler. because of this problem quartz running twice.

Using Quartz-2.1.1 and Spring framework 3.1.1

The quartz configuration is as follows :

```
<bean id="simpleTrigger" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SimpleTriggerFactoryBean">
        <property name="jobDetail" ref="jobDetail" />
        <property name="startDelay" value="10000" />
        <property name="repeatInterval" value="1000" />
</bean>

<bean id="sc" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean">
        <property name="triggers">
            <list>
                <ref bean="simpleTrigger" />
            </list>
        </property>
</bean>

<bean id="jobDetail" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean">
    <property name="targetObject" ref="staFromInQObj" />
        <property name="targetMethod" value="processInQueueData" />
        <property name="concurrent" value="false" />
</bean>
```

Comment: can you post your quartz config files.

Comment: The problem could be with your quartz configuration and may not with your tomcat deployment.

Comment: Have edited the question with the configurations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is the correct answer for the problem.
[Spring 3 MVC dispatcher xml and applicationContext xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5009901/spring-3-mvc-dispatcher-xml-and-applicationcontext-xml)
Double deployments can happen due to spring configs as well !