# Spring - TimerTask implementation running twice

Tags: java, spring, tomcat7, timertask

I have a simple TimerTask implementation that just prints to the System.out

```
public class RefreshUserAndOLStatsJob extends TimerTask {  
   public void run() {
     System.out.println("RefreshUserAndOLStatsJob running at: " + new Date(this.scheduledExecutionTime()));     
   }
}
```

It is configured in the Spring application context as follows

```
<bean id="refreshUserAndOLStatsTask" class="org.springframework.scheduling.timer.ScheduledTimerTask">
    <!-- run every 30 secs -->
    <property name="period" value="30000" />
    <property name="timerTask" ref="refreshUserAndOLStatsJob" />
</bean>
<bean class="org.springframework.scheduling.timer.TimerFactoryBean">
    <property name="scheduledTimerTasks">
        <list>
            <ref local="refreshUserAndOLStatsTask" />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

It is supposed to run every 30 seconds. Which it does but does so twice for each run, as is evident from the System out

```
RefreshUserAndOLStatsJob running at: Thu Feb 14 20:59:01 IST 2013
RefreshUserAndOLStatsJob running at: Thu Feb 14 20:59:02 IST 2013
RefreshUserAndOLStatsJob running at: Thu Feb 14 20:59:31 IST 2013
RefreshUserAndOLStatsJob running at: Thu Feb 14 20:59:32 IST 2013
RefreshUserAndOLStatsJob running at: Thu Feb 14 21:00:01 IST 2013
RefreshUserAndOLStatsJob running at: Thu Feb 14 21:00:02 IST 2013
RefreshUserAndOLStatsJob running at: Thu Feb 14 21:00:31 IST 2013
RefreshUserAndOLStatsJob running at: Thu Feb 14 21:00:32 IST 2013
RefreshUserAndOLStatsJob running at: Thu Feb 14 21:01:01 IST 2013
RefreshUserAndOLStatsJob running at: Thu Feb 14 21:01:02 IST 2013
RefreshUserAndOLStatsJob running at: Thu Feb 14 21:01:31 IST 2013
```

Can someone guess why it could be so.

EDIT 1 : I am on Tomcat7

EDIT 2 : On adding the hashCode, as suspected by Matt, there are 2 separate instances of RefreshUserAndOLStatsJob. It seems that the application context IS indeed being initialized twice.

As for the initialization of refreshUserAndOLStatsJob in application context xml, it is not explicitly declared, but because RefreshUserAndOLStatsJob is a class marked as @Component, it seems Spring can load it automatically.

Comment: Nothing seems to stand out, so a few questions: Is this the only `TimerFactoryBean` in your application context?  Do you know if the context get loaded multiple times?  Where is the `refreshUserAndOLStatsJob` bean initialized?

Comment: Maybe another thing to try to help debug this would be to add `System.out.println(hashCode());` to your task's run method to see if it's the same `RefreshUserAndOLStatsJob` object or two separate ones. Assuming you haven't overridden `hashCode`, it'll execute the `Object` implementation which should be different for two separate objects.

Comment: Just out of interest is there any reason you aren't using the newer method of scheduling tasks? See here http://blog.springsource.org/2010/01/05/task-scheduling-simplifications-in-spring-3-0/

Comment: @Matt, super suggestions. See the updated answer. It seems the context is being loaded multiple times. I wonder why that is.

Comment: @Niall Thomson : No particular reason. Just that new things have a new learning curve.

Comment: Is it possible that you are manually loading the app context in your code as well as loading it via the ContextLoaderListener?

Comment: @EricGalluzzo : Thanks. It was not initialized twice in code but in web.xml. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5009901/spring-3-mvc-dispatcher-xml-and-applicationcontext-xml

Comment: See my last comment. I made the mistake of initializing app context twice.

Comment: my setup is based on annotations & I do not have any duplicate definitions. seems your situation is different from mine. @arahant